# How can I store processes metrics data for a longer time beyond the default 24 hr retention period in GCP ops agent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics, retention, google-cloud-ops-agent

Currently there is only 24 hrs retention period for all processes metrics collected by ops agent in gcp. As per the documentations no configuration changes can be made to change this default value. Is there any other way to increase it's retention period or any way to store those processes metrics data for a longer time? so that they can be visualized later...

Any help would be appreciated!!

Explored the documentations, no solution found.

Comment: Can you check the mentioned [link](https://www.doit.com/increase-log-retention-using-google-cloud-logging-cli/) as it will be useful to you.

Comment: The link is for logs but OP is asking about metrics. 24h is a hard limit for process metrics and it cannot be increased. You can look into exporting metrics to BigQuery for long-term analysis: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export

Comment: yeah it only seems the possible way. Else, we can go for Prometheus. Thank you though!